# How can I hide files and icons on KDE desktop?

Tags: kde, icons

I'm not a fan of desktop icons, to me they are clutter, so that is the first thing I disable in GNOME on Ubuntu. Now I have a desktop with KDE and many people on the Internet tell others with this question that they can only delete the icons or use a different (empty) folder.

(Which looks so wrong to me, because I remember reading about early KDE 4 versions which had no desktop icons because this was not implemented back then.)

Comment: There is no OS/release mentioned  (details as to your software stack provide us with details as to your KDE version, Qt5/6 stack etc)

Answer (score 4):

`FolderView` is the widget which is used to display the contents of a folder on your screen. See the built-in help document:

[image]

To disable `Folder View` on your desktop, right-click somewhere on your desktop and choose `Configure Desktop and Wallpaper...` from the context menu:

[image]

Here change the `Layout` from `Folder View` to `Desktop` and then click the `Apply`-button.

[Here](https://technastic.com/configure-kde-plasma-desktop/#KDE_Plasma_Desktop_Wallpaper) is a pretty detailed guide, hope you'll find it useful.

Comment: I read that in some comments somewhere else but failed to see the forest for the trees. KDE feels overwhelming when you are used to different desktop environments. Could you please provide a few more screenshots and highlight where to click? Or if there is a KDE documentation site that does it better then please link there. I remember that they had a site with GIF animations a few years ago, but I cannot find it. The menu also changes when you change the layout and you need to click apply to apply the change. It sounds silly, I know but could you improve your answer a bit so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to achieve what you are looking for is to open a terminal in the respective desktop folder and run the following command which creates a `.hidden` file with all filenames in the current directory:

```bash
ls -1 > .hidden
```

It's quite easy to type. It's a plain text file which you can edit and you can run the command again to update (overwrite) the contents of the file.

All you have to do is to log out and back in. I guess KDE needs to be triggerd to render this view again. May be creating and removing a temporary file will also work, I have not tried yet.

From my point of view that is the more constructive way instead of arguing with other users of filing feature requests.

Comment: Amazing! How in the world this answer haven't received more upvotes?